# The provided dynamic link domain is not configured or authorized for the current project

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

My aim is sending email for sign up users using Firebase function and authentication.
I followed [Firebase example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth).
But it tells below error message.

> The provided dynamic link domain is not configured or authorized for
>   the current project

My code is at below.

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
    url: 'https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234',
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    iOS: {
      bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
    },
    android: {
      packageName: 'com.example.android',
      installApp: true,
      minimumVersion: '12'
    },
    dynamicLinkDomain: 'example.page.link'
};


exports.sendmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return cors(req, res, () => {
        firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail("sungyong@humminglab.io", actionCodeSettings)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            res.status(200).send(userCredential);
            res.status(200).send(userCredential);
            return;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(error)
            // ...
            res.status(400).send(error);
        });
    });
});
```

Here are my configuration at my console.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`example.page.link` is not configured as a dynamic link domain for your project.

You need to use one you own. You can get that from "Dynamic Links" under "Grow" in the left menu of the Firebase Console.

If you don't need to use dynamic links with mobile flows, just change to:

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
  // Replace this URL with the URL where the user will complete sign-in.
  url: 'https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234',
  handleCodeInApp: true
};
```

Comment: Hi, After i press on the link sent to my email, how does my expo app listen this in order to navigate to the next page?

Comment: @kd12345 use deeplinking

Answer (score 2):

Add "example.page.link" in the Authorised domain instead of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
Because example.page.link is your domain id.